# AP8941 PDU frozen, how to reset management interface?

Tags: power-distribution-unit, apc

I have a frozen AP8941 PDU. It still produces power to its outlets, but I can't serial in, ethernet in and even the LCD is frozen.
How do I reset it without losing power on the outlets? (I prefer a simple reboot of the management interface than a reset to factory default obviously).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have physical access to the PDU, just use a paper clip to press the reset button. It won't affect the outlet status.

Comment: that worked for the serial and Ethernet interfaces, The LCD and its buttons, however, is still frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else needs to reset the Serial or Web Interface password...

I had to Press and Hold the Reset button for ~5 Secs, then release. I then waited ~3 Secs, and the Status Light started to flash Green/Orange(Eth Status Light). I press the Reset Button one last time. After than I waited for ~1 Min then I was able to access serial again with Default information.

Simple Pressing the Reset Button then Waiting for the status light to flash and pressing it a second time, did not work for me... The LCD showed that it was resetting the Web Interface but the Password was not reset to default.

For me I had to do a combination of Pressing and Holding.

Links:
https://manualsdump.com/en/manuals/apc-ap8941-ap89xx/154988/17

What gave me the idea to hold the button
https://www.tekinaka.com/apc-metered-rack-pdu-password-recovery/